# ThinkPad T430 Linux

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, thinkpad, lts

Forgive me if this is a question that has been asked many times before. I am a complete newbie when it comes to Ubuntu, or Linux for that matter. I just received a ThinkPad T430 without an operating system. Considering installing ubuntu but recommended is vr 12.04 lts. Can I install 16.04 lts without major issues?
Machine specs are Intel i7, 8gb ram, I think it's Nvidia?, 240 GB ssd. 
Thanks in advance! 
Dariusz

Comment: Probably yes, but configurations vary (http://www.lapspecs.com/detail/lenovo+thinkpad+t430). The specific graphics card and network card may require proprietary drivers or not. Cf. http://blog.burntsushi.net/lenovo-thinkpad-t430-archlinux/ where no problems were found with Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2200 and Intel HD Graphics 4000.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can.
Check for more info here after you install, which will largely help you settle in:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but if you want to just test it and make sure everything works I suggest creating a Live USB/CD and try that.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Once you have tested it out, and you are not having issues you can install it directly from the Live version.  Come back here if you need any more help, or have any more questions.